# How to pass html attributes to wtf.form_field when using flask-wtf and flask-bootstrap

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, wtforms

I have some form in template rendered with flask-bootstrap macro:

```
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.name) }}
```

but I want to do this also:

```
{{ form.name(class="form-control", placeholder='Name', maxlength=20, size=20) }}
```

How can I possibly pass html attributes to `form_field` function? I know about `render_kw` argument in `wtfforms` Field class constructor, but I want to set attributes in template and not in python code!
Maybe you can tell me about some cool pattern for `flask-wtf` and `flask-bootstrap` (or just `bootstrap`) or just answer my question :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I got it finally
I just can do this:

```
 wtf.form_field(form.name, class="form-control", placeholder='Name', maxlength=5, size=20)
```

I read macro definition and found "kwargs" argument
It's not in arguments list but somehow available in scope
Obviously, I need to find out more about macro :)